# algorithm goes in infinite loop with for cycle in PHP, why?

Tags: php, for-loop

can you explain me, what is wrong with the code? I tried to get rid of all elements which are not 1 or 2...

```
    $current_groups = [1,2,3,4];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($current_groups); $i++){
        if ($current_groups[$i]!= 1 and $current_groups[$i] != 2){
            unset($current_groups[$i]);
            $i = $i - 1;
        }
    }
    echo print_r($current_groups, true);
```

it goes in infinit loop unexpectedly ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your for loop definition, `$i` is incremented after each iteration.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($current_groups); $i++){
```

Then in the body, with `$i = $i - 1;`, it's set back to the previous value. So, basically it never changes.

You could probably use `array_filter` to do this instead.

```
$current_groups = array_filter($current_groups, function($x) {
    return $x == 1 || $x == 2;
});
```

Or `array_intersect` (Thanks to @Chris for the idea.)

```
$current_groups = array_intersect($current_groups, [1,2]);
```

Comment: thank you very much for the solution, I will definitely use it. But according to my code, I thought that when there won't be 3 and 4 in array, the loop will increase the $i variable till the size of array and stop, isn't it?

Comment: @Don't Panic `array_diff()` wouldn't be more simple than `array_filter()`? (just a theoretical question, not tested) `$current_groups = array_diff($current_groups, [1, 2]);`

Comment: @SergeyVladimirovich The loop _does_ increase the `$i` variable. But when you use `$i = $i - 1;` inside the loop, it negates that.

Comment: @Chris good idea! I think the goal is to keep the 1 and 2 values and get rid of the others, though. `array_intersect` can do that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic My bad, you are right ;) I understood the opposite the first time I read.

Comment: @Chris I actually did too. The first version of the `array_filter` that I added did the opposite.